# Python: What does file.read() do?

Tags: python

- OS: Ubuntu
- Language: Python

So I'm trying to read the bytes of a file. I created a script that just uses file.read() and it iterates through the bytes. It comes to a character where is looks like

```
[ 0 0 ]
[ 0 3 ]
```

I guess my real question is: What does this character repersent? When I look at a Hex Editor, it displays it as ú which makes sense because the hexidecimal is FA.

Comment: What is the encoding of the file being read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file.read` will take the binary contents of your declared file and stuff it into a buffer.

00 and 03 are control characters (00 = `NULL`, 03 = `END OF TEXT`). You may be interested in referring to an ASCII table for more details.

**ASCII Table**: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif